# Cannot ping my own router on any Linux distro (ethernet)

Tags: linux, networking, router, internet, ethernet

I've tried multiple distros, all failed.  I always run Windows 10 (ethernet and wifi work fine) but I dual boot and changed my distro from Arch (~6 months ago) to Fedora (~3 months), and Fedora used to sometimes connect and sometimes not.  However, now it won't connect at all.  Antergos won't.  Debian won't.  Arch won't.  I've reset my router and modem and I've even tried this at another house and it still doesn't connect.  If I set a static IP, it "connects", but I still can't access the internet.  Pinging google or even my own router doesn't work.  Any help?  I've already spent about 2 hours looking up and trying answers with no avail.  There are also only Windows drivers for my ethernet on my MB.  Thanks.

edit: the message I get when pinging any address is destination host unreachable.

crossposted from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275582/cannot-connect-to-the-internet-even-pinging-my-own-router-on-any-distro

Comment: What static ip did you set? What's the ip of the router? Are they in the same network?  What subnet mask?

Comment: IP: 192.168.0.129 (starts at 100 and ends at 140 in my router config, I'm the only one with devices connected atm and it's just an iPhone, iPad, and my PC.  I also tried others like 139 and in between with no luck), the router is 192.168.0.1, they are in the same network, subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: It's not what I assumed, but you know what they say about that word =]

Comment: Did you set static IP **randomly**?

Comment: @Alexiy What do you mean "randomly"?  I chose an IP that wasn't already being used if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you know that you have to set router's IP to the one provided by ISP. Does your ISP give dynamic or static IP to the computer?

Comment: This sounds like you have something configured incorrectly... First off, (although I doubt it's the problem) a static IP address should be OUTSIDE of your DHCP range, so if DHCP is 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.140, your IP should be something like 192.168.0.25. What is the output of `ifconfig` and `ip route show`?